# Notation for pre-image in the context of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, borel-sets

The following definition of a real-valued random variable (evidently) uses the notation $\{ X \in B \}$ for the pre-image of $B$ under $X$:

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. A random variable is a real-valued function $X$ defined on $\Omega$ with the property that for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the subset of $\Omega$ given by

$$ \{X \in B \} = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B \} $$

is in the $\sigma$-algebra $F$.

(The definition is more or less quoted from Steve Shreve’s text on stochastic calculus for finance.)

Is $\{ X \in B \}$ a common way to write the pre-image in the context of random variables? Is there some background or motivation for this notation?

Comment: Yes, using $P(X\in B)$ for $P(\{\omega\in \Omega\,:\, X(\omega)\in B\})$ is quite common, more or less like verbally you would refer to the probability that the result of a die roll is $6$ rather than to the probability of the set of instances where the result of the die roll is $6$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Here is discussion that touches on similar topics. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694548/formal-definition-of-a-random-variable?rq=1

Comment: Also this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516284/definition-of-a-real-valued-random-variable